# Declare Date Type Global Variable and pass that to Child Job from Parent Job

Tags: talend

I want to create a `Date` type global variable which I want to pass to a child job. I am able to pass `String` and `Integer` type to child one. But getting hard luck with `Date` type as shown in this image:

[image]

Below is the code I am writing in my *tjavarow*. In the child job context the variables pass this global variable's value. And I'm using those, now, in the child job `toracleInput`. I have to use the two `Date` type Contexts where the global variable `Value` will be coming from the parent job.

**This is my code:**

```
String fromdate_file_epsilon=input_row.START_DATE1; 
globalMap.put("fromdate_file_epsilon", fromdate_file_epsilon);
String todate_file_epsilon = input_row.END_DATE1; 
globalMap.put("todate_file_epsilon",todate_file_epsilon); 
Date fromdate_epsilon = input_row.START_DATE;
globalMap.put("fromdate_epsilon", fromdate_epsilon); 
Date todate_epsilon = input_row.END_DATE; 
globalMap.put("todate_epsilon", todate_epsilon); 
Integer load_key_epsilon = input_row.LOAD_KEY;
globalMap.put("load_key_epsilon", load_key_epsilon);
System.out.println(fromdate_epsilon);
```

I am passing the global variable values of the parent job to the child job's context values like `Brand=((String)globalMap.get("brand_epsilon")` on the `ChildJob` component.

Comment: I am using this code in tjavarow

Comment: Why don't you define your context variables as date type, and then assign the value you want to them (context.myDate = row.myDate). In tRunJob, check the "transmit whole context" option to pass all the context variables. In your child job just reference the context.myDate which is already a date type, no need to cast it.

Comment: I incorporated two of your comments into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I proposed on Talend Community Forum, I strongly recommend you to leave date context variables as string and to convert the values as Oracle datatype using the to_date function into the where clause like this:

`...
AND TRUNC(ACTIVITY_DATE) >= TO_DATE('" + context.FROMDATE + "', 'yyyy_mm-dd')"
...`

date format is given here as an example.

TRF